# Simulating clicks, keyboard input etc in a web view?

Tags: vb.net, winforms, visual-studio

I have decided to have some fun with VB.NET and make a bot for some online games.
First of all, I plan on viewing the game through a webview control, which I believe is perfectly possible... unless I can't see Flash/Java content?

If it *is* possible, I've been wondering how would you "simulate a click" in the web view control? And, of course, keyboard input?

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps a little late and I have no experience with VB.NET but to work with keys on a web page you need to use Javascript. For example:

```
<html>
<head>
  <script>
    document.onkeyup = function(event){ console.log(event); };
  </script>
</head>
<body>
  press a key within this document.
</body>
</html>
```

Cursor keys don't generate a keypress event hence the use of onkeyup. Also note it's lowercase. onKeyUp is not correct. If you're using Chrome or Firefox console.log will output the object that you can inspect. Not sure about IE but I think later versions support this too. Properties and methods can be used to get the keycode, character and any modifiers.

This code was tested on Chrome 12 beta. There are differences between IE and other browsers (as usual). This page shows an example of some of the differences: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onkeypress.asp

Not sure what you mean by "simulate a click" but I suspect you're not referring to testing.

Comment: Don't forget to set  Settings.IsScriptNotifyAllowed = True and Settings.IsJavaScriptEnabled = True

Answer (score 0):

Try for [WatiN](http://Watin.org), its like testing a web application